# How to find all the eigenvalues of a positive operator whose eigenvectors are positive semi-defintie？

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

A linear operator $T:\mathcal{H}_n\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_n$ is said to be positive if $T(\mathcal{P}_n)\subset\mathcal{P}_n$ where $P_n$ is the set of positive semi-definite matrices. For a positive operator, we have the Krein-Rutman Theorem, i.e., $\rho(\mathcal{T})$ is an eigenvalue of the positive operator $\mathcal{T}$ together with an eigenvector $X\in\mathcal{P}_n$, $X\neq 0$ such that $\mathcal{T}(X)=\rho(\mathcal{T})X.$

A subset of spectrum is defined as: 
$$\sigma_{_{\mathcal{P}}}(T)
=\{\lambda\in\sigma(T): T(X)=\lambda X, X\in\mathcal{P}_n,X\neq 0\}.$$

***My question*** is: How can I find **all** the eigenvalues in $\sigma_{_{\mathcal{P}}}(T)$ , especially for positive operators with the form of 
$$T:X\in\mathcal{H}_n\rightarrow AXA'+BXB'\in\mathcal{H}_n,$$
where $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

I know how to work with the simple cases. However, I'm wondering whether there exist some algorithms for such problems.